# Запросы в Mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть такие схемы, нарисовал нужные мне столбцы:

```
 p_table

------------      
|V_ID|KARTA|
-----------
|1752|32|
--------
a_table
A_ID-unique
-----------
|A_ID|NAME|
-----------
|12|MyName|
-----------

v_table

V_ID-unique

----------------
|V_ID|K_ID|A_ID |T_ID|
-----------
|1752|5   | 12  |101|
----------
|1753|9 |  12  |117|
----------------

S_table

-----------
|T_ID|C_ID|V_ID|
-----------
|117|73|1753|
-------------

Мне нужно,собственно,
```

1-сначала с таблицы а брать по а*ИД,а*ИМЯ, 
 2-потом по а_ИД связывать таблицу v по v_id,
 3- и по этим v_id связывать таблиц p table (где K_ID=5 то v_table.v_id=p_table.v_id)и
 s table (где k_id=9 то v_table.t_id=s_table.t_id and s_table.v_id=v_table._v_id)
 4-нужно типа `select Имя from описанные_таблицы;`

Я вот так пробовал, но выдаеть ошибку на limit:

```
SELECT a.name

FROM
  a_table a  , v_table v
  ,p_table p,s_table s
  WHERE
a.a_id = v.a_id 
 AND (v.v_id in (select group_concat(v_id) from v_table where a_id=(select a.a_id) group by a_id limit 1))
/*ругаеться на это лимит*/
     AND (v.k_id in (5,9))  
      AND v.v_id=p.v_id and p.karta=32 and s.v_id=v.v_id and s.t_id=117 and s.c_id=73 
    GROUP BY  a.a_id
```

Comment: или как я понял, внутри селект-а нельзя использовать лимит???

Comment: внутри IN нельзя использовать limit, доки по мускулу почитать следует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT a.name

    FROM
      a_table a  , v_table v
      ,p_table p,s_table s
      WHERE
    a.a_id = v.a_id 
     AND (v.v_id in (select group_concat(v_id) from v_table where a_id=(select a.a_id 
// ЧТО??? это пипец! Из какой таблицы с каким условием??
) group by a_id limit 0,1))
    /*ругаеться на это лимит*/
         AND (v.k_id in (5,9))  
          AND v.v_id=p.v_id and p.karta=32 and s.v_id=v.v_id and s.t_id=117 and s.c_id=73 
        GROUP BY  a.a_id
```

А вообще предложу пересмотреть конструкцию твоей выборки.
**
    (v.v_id=(select group_concat(v_id) from v_table where a_id=a.a_id group by a_id)

**
жестоко особенно 
    a_id=(select a.a_id)

Йопта. Звиняйте! Код бред.
    (v.v_id in (select group_concat(v_id) from v_table where a_id=(select a.a_id) group by a_id limit 0,1))

**Вопрос, нафига тебе IN (и тут всего одна выборка?)**

Comment: SQL4.sql: Ошибка: (3,1): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Если чесно, то вообще перепиши весь запрос, я его не проверяю ибо не на чем, но то что ты так вот делаешь выборку убивает.

Используй **JOIN**

Comment: потому что в таблице р и s v_id разные,хотя их a_id одинаковые.

Comment: А то что мускул выдал
>SQL4.sql: Ошибка: (3,1): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support >'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Правильно сделал ибо в IN() такая штука никогда не прокатит даже в 6й версии.

Comment: Хорошо,понял. Спасибо за отзыв!

Comment: Да собственно не за что.